# How to customize post type slugs

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug, post-type

In my wp site I've got 3 post type: one is just the standard wp post, and the other two are custom post types (location and coupons).  I've set a custom permalink structure so that /blog/ will be in every post url.  But /blog/ also prepends every location and coupon post url as well.  How can I make it so /blog/ only appears on the standard wp posts, and the custom post types can have their respective slugs?

Comment: How did you set the custom permalink structure for your wp post? It would be right place to check, why it also affects the custom post types. Please share your code or settings.

Comment: Under settings => Permalinks => custom structure : /blog/%postname%/

Comment: and how did you register you custom post types? if using code, please give use the code.

Comment: I registered them via the CPT UI

Comment: Here is the query I used for the location PT:
    $locations_query = new WP_Query(array(
                            'post_type'         => 'locations',
                            'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
                            'orderby'           => 'ID',
                            'order'             => 'DESC',
                            'post_status'       => array('publish', 'draft')
                        ));

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code in a formatted way. Also tell the community that you are using this and that plugin and did this and that configuration. This way your chances of getting a good answer will be much higher.